# separator in string template

Tags: stringtemplate

I have the following code in a stringtemplate file:

```
(1)    Module $component$ = new Module(new GeometryDescription[] {$shapes;separator=", "$});
```

which i know is wrong as what I would like is to be able to generate multiple of this line

so that when i call a list of components Component1(North, part1, part2)
                                         Component2(North, part1, part2,part3)
i get the following:

```
  Module North = new Module(new GeometryDescription[] {part1,part2});
  Module South = new Module(new GeometryDescription[] {part1,part2,part3});
```

how can i write sentence (1) to be able to do that
thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap (1) in a template and then map that template across your list of components.

Comment: thanks my question was actually in the grammar. I had the (1) in template but I could not get it right the grammar, finally i found out:)  $components: {unit|  
        ModuleComponentDescription $unit.name +"Component"$ = new ModuleComponentDescription(new GeometryDescription[] $unit.id:{shape|$shape.name$};separator=","$);}$